# Input text validation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using `Jquery` Framework, I'm trying to validate input data, which is not equal to null or empty string. My approach is to validate data in a single line as I'm maintaining cookies storage. My question is, how can I validate input text that value its not an empty string, similarly I checked radio buttons and check boxes that are checked. How can I validate input[type='text'] with same condition input[value !=''] in a single line.

**Here's my code:**

```
_strFormElements = "input[type='text']," + 
                        "input[type='checkbox']:checked," + 
                        "input[type='radio']:checked," +
                        "input[type='image']," + 
                        "input[type='file']," + 
                        "select," + 
                        "textarea";
```

I then checking as follow, but I want to check and validate before theses checks as my init method creates empty feilds before this.

```
if (elem.is('input:text') || elem.is('input:hidden') || elem.is('input:image') ||
                        elem.is('input:file') || elem.is('textarea')) {
                    elem.val(value);
            }
```

**My Try:**

I've tried `input[type='text' value != '']` but I'm unable to check this in a single line.

Comment: `elem.val(value);` isn't checking anything. It's setting a value.

Comment: yeah, my point is, I want to validate the input text feild before setting the value.